# Is it possible to use XLA in Tensorflow with variable input shape?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, jit, tensorflow-xla

Trying to use XLA to further enhance the performance and speed up the training of my model in TF2.10. However, my input data shape varies, i.e.  `batch.shape = TensorShape([X, 4])` with X varying between batches.

In case of static execution without XLA, *i.e.* decorating the python update step function with `@tf.function(jit_compile=False)`, and obtaining a concrete function for an input signature with `shape = [None, 4]` avoids retracing for every new X shape. However, if `jit_compile=True`, although no retracing occurs for calls with new shapes, however the first update_step call on a new `X` requires a very large amount of time.

The question is if there exists any method to avoid large compilation times on `tf.graph` with XLA and newly encountered shapes.

### Code:

```
# the update function 
@tf.function(jit_compile=IS_XLA)
def update_step(model, optim, batch):
   ... 
   return loss

# Training function 
def train_model(model, optim, all_batches):
   concrete_update_step = update_step.get_concrete_function(model=model, optim=optim, // 
            batch=tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, 4), dtype=tf.float32))
   
   for batch in all_batches:
      loss =  concrete_update_step(batch)
   
   return None 



if __name__ == '__main__':

# run without XLA
IS_XLA = False
for epoch in range(N_epochs):
  train_model(model,optim,all_batches)

### Tracing occurs only for the call on the first batch 



# run with XLA 
IS_XLA = True 
for epoch in range(N_epochs):
  train_model(model,optim,all_batches)

### Although tracing occurs only for the call on the first batch, however for every new batch.shape[0], calling concrete_update_step requires huge amount of time
```